# How can I center div in div in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float, internet-explorer-7

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;    
}

.wrapper .box{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#F00;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

I want to center all div in wrapper div like this;[image]

Above codes work fine in IE8,IE9,Chrome,Safari,Opera,FF but not working in IE7. When I open page in IE7, page looks like this;

[image]

If I use float:left, the problem seems to be solved but all divs based on the left. How can I solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/eBxFX/2/

Comment: the width of the wrapper is constant or it may change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline-block doesn't work in IE7.

You have to use zoom:1 and display:inline as a hack or without hack from a different css only for ie7.

```
.wrapper .box{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom:1;
    background:#F00;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eBxFX/4/