# Centering div in IE7

Tags: css

my div is left aligned in IE7. It works in newer browsers but not in older. It should be centered. My code is

```
#contentarea {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    max-width:100%; 

}
```

Is there a way to make the div appear in the center in IE7? thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I center div in div in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461917/how-can-i-center-div-in-div-in-ie7)

Comment: Thanks this solution does not work for me. I am trying to center the entire container.

Comment: Your case must be different then.

Comment: Yes this is one of the pages http://www.ferngrottokauai.com/privacypolicy.htm the containtarea is pushed to the left on IE7 and it should be in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#contentarea {
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-460px;
    width: 920px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: If neither `margin: 0 auto;` nor the negative `margin-left:` hack above work, you might have a styles clash somewhere else in your stylesheet. Can you reveal more of your stylesheet in an update to your question above?

Comment: Hi Rounin, here is my stylesheet http://www.ferngrottokauai.com/Portals/1/Skins/ferngrotto-responsive-s.1.0/skin.css

Comment: Hi @Parlanchina - I've run `position:relative; left:50%; margin-left:-460px;` through the IE7 tab on IETester and it is working for me. Are you sure it's not working? (Make sure you include `position:relative;` - I omitted to include it the first time.)

Comment: Thanks Rounin! I tried again and it worked. So yes, your solution works! thank you! May I ask one more question. on all browsers my slider on the homepage is pushed to the left http://www.ferngrottokauai.com/. I wonder if there is a fix for that and make it in the middle?